# Why do the memory locations of the elements in my 2D array keep changing in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Within the other functions of my program I read data from a file and then enter it in to a 2d array. This 2D array is pointed to in a struct with the use of a struct member that is a double pointer. I then using this 2D array within a new function.

In this function I'm trying to open a new file in write mode, and then write the contents of the 2d array in to the file using a double for loop. However, this part was not working at all.
When I tried printing out each individual element it would print the first element of the array correctly. But after that every other element was some random symbol like l, @, ?, H which were symbols that were completely unrelated and were never stored in the array.

```
    outfile = fopen( "test.txt", "w");
    //error handling


    if(outfile == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");   
      exit(1);             
   }
   // printf("\nfirst element %c\n",u->unipointer[4][3]);

    //this aims to print out every element in the 2d array
    for (int i=0; i<u->rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<u->cols; j++){
            printf("%c",u->unipointer[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nfirst element %c\n",u->unipointer[0][0]);
    printf("first element %c\n",u->unipointer[0][0]);




    fclose(outfile);

}
```

The double for loops don't print anything.
When I print u->unipointer[0][0] the first time I get '.' which is the actual value that is stored in the 2D array. 
When I print it a second time, in exactly the same way, I get 'H' for some reason. This is the same for any other element in the 2D array that I try to print individually.

When I print out the memory location of these two elements they are different. However, each time I run the program the, memory location on the first print line does not change, but the second line changes every time.

Comment: We can't debug incomplete code. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah, a full (but minimal) example would be helpful.  My first guess based on no information: you are exceeding your array limits.  I'd want to see the code to allocate and fill the array and then print the output.

Comment: Show the declaration and initialization of `u` and `u->unipointer`. I suspect your are using the wrong conversion specifier. But at this point, my crystal ball won't even tell me the type for `u->unipointer` -- they don't make 'em like they used to... A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: unipointer is a double pointer of type char